# How to create flag 0/1 inform whether was changed or not during 4 months between two columns in PROC SQL in SAS Enterprise Guide?

Tags: sql, time, sas, proc-sql, enterprise-guide

I have table in SAS Enterprise Guide like below:

name of table: table123

date typ:

- ID - numeric
- DT - numeric
- VAL1 - string
- VAL2 - string

| ID | DT | VAL1 | VAL2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | 20210523 | PR | P |
| 123 | 20211222 | P | P |
| 222 | 20210502 | PR | M |
| 222 | 20210711 | M | PR |
| 38 | 20210513 | PR | PR |
| 991 | 20211123 | M | P |

And I need to create column "COL1" with values 0/1:

- If ID changed value from column "VAL1" from PR to value P or M in column "VAL2" and has not changed back to PR for 4 months or more -> 1 else 0

SO I need something like below:

| ID | DT | VAL1 | VAL2 | COL1 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | 20210523 | PR | P | 1 |
| 123 | 20211222 | P | P | 1 |
| 222 | 20210502 | PR | M | 0 |
| 222 | 20210711 | M | PR | 0 |
| 38 | 20210513 | PR | PR | 0 |
| 991 | 20211123 | M | P | 0 |

Because:

- 123 - has 1 in "COL1" because changed PR to P and does not changed back to PR for 4 month or more
- 222 - has 0 in "COL1" because changed PR to M but did not last like this for at least 4 months (after 2 months backed to PR)
- 38 - has 0 in "COL1" because did not change PR to P or M
- 991 - has 0 in "COL1" because did not change PR to P or M

How can I do that in SAS Enterprise Guide in PROC SQL ?

Comment: why do you not save dates as dates, convertion costs always lots if time and resources

Comment: Such data I have in the database, could you present your solution of above problem, please ? ;)

Comment: When you say DT is a number do you mean it literally has numbers like 20,210,523 instead of an actual date value? Or does it have actual date values that are being displayed with the YYMMDDN8. format so it prints like 20210523?  You can check the TYPE and any format attached to the variable be seeing the output of PROC CONTENTS run on the dataset.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll want to use a data step for this one since it uses fairly complex logic. You must first convert your date into a SAS date for this to work.

```
data col1_flag;
    set have;
    by id dt;

    /* Do not reset these variables to missing at each row */
    retain flag_pr_to_p_pm dt_from_pr_to_p_m;
    
    /* Reset flags and dates at each new ID */
    if(first.id) then call missing(flag_pr_to_p_pm, dt_from_pr_to_p_m);

    /* If PR (VAL1) changes to P or M (VAL2), then set a flag. If VAL1
       changes back from P or M, reset the flag to 0*/
    if(VAL1 = 'PR' and VAL2 IN('P', 'M') ) then do;
        flag_pr_to_p_pm = 1;

        /* Store the number of months when it originally went from PR --> P or M */
        dt_from_pr_to_p_m = dt;     
    end;
        else if(VAL1 NOT IN ('P', 'M') ) then flag_pr_to_p_pm = 0;
    
    /* 1. We've encountered a situation where PR --> P or M
       2. It's been 4 months since PR --> P or M
       3. P or M has not changed back to PR
       4. OR: There's one row that goes from PR --> P or M
    */
    COL1 = (    flag_pr_to_p_pm
            AND intck('month', dt_from_pr_to_p_m, dt) > 4 
            AND NOT (VAL1 IN('P', 'M') AND VAL2 = 'PR')
            OR (flag_pr_to_p_pm AND first.id AND last.id)
           )
    ;

    if(COL1) then output;

    format dt_from_pr_to_p_m date9.;

    keep id;
run;
```

Output:

```
ID  DT          VAL1    VAL2    COL1
38  13MAY2021   PR      PR      0
123 23MAY2021   PR      P       1
123 22DEC2021   P       P       1
222 02MAY2021   PR      M       0
222 11JUL2021   M       PR      0
991 23NOV2021   M       P       0
```

Comment: Stu Sztukowski, did you converted in your code date in SAS date ?

Comment: I did it before reading the data to create a sample dataset. You can easily do it in the code though.

Comment: could you modify your code so as to also modify format of DT column, please? ;) I am not good in SAS

Comment: Szutkowski, could you modify your code to change format of my date colun to correct ? so as to be able use your solution ? :)

Comment: The code has been modified but I highly suggest you read about how to convert date formats with the `input()` function. https://go.documentation.sas.com/doc/en/pgmsascdc/9.4_3.5/lefunctionsref/p19en16vskd2vhn1vwmxpxnglxxs.htm

Comment: Stu Szukowki, did you create new table using your code? If yes what is the name ? I do not see that in code ?

Comment: Yes, you can see this at the top of the code where `dt` is being converted to a SAS date. If you need it to be a new table name then you can modify the code to do so. Everything you need is right here. If you need additional help on SAS coding I recommend taking a free training class offered by SAS online, or read through the documentation of the DATA Step. https://documentation.sas.com/doc/en/pgmsascdc/9.4_3.5/basess/n053a58fwk57v7n14h8x7y7u34y4.htm

Comment: Stu Sztukowski could you modify your code so as to create new table with yout solution please ?

Comment: As a reminder, Stack Overflow is not a code writing service. You can modify the code to work within the data and existing code that you have. I do not know what your existing code looks like and cannot know what the dataset name should be. You must have a basic knowledge of SAS programming to be able to work with solutions posted here. The solution I have posted for you is fully commented. Any additional questions can be found via search, SAS documentation, or from one of the free SAS programming courses offered online. Given the code you have, experiment modifying it to create a new table.

Comment: I checked your solution and unfortunately it does not return correct answer :/

Comment: Does the value of 1 or 0 need to be applied to all rows for an ID where this case occurs? Can you post sample data where this solution does not work?

Comment: Stu Sztukowski - everything is great! But one more think I forgot - when we have only one row per some client where is PR in "VAL1" and M or P in "VAL2" this kind of client also should have 1 in flag - could you modify your solution for that ?

Comment: The code has been updated to account for this situation.