# How to create 0/1 flag witch infrom whether values were changed between 2 column in some dates in PROC SQL in SAS Enterprise Guide?

Tags: sql, date, sas, proc-sql, enterprise-guide

I have table in SAS Enterprise Guide like below. Table presents history of clients and his eventually changes of services used (columns: BEFORE, AGAIN).

ID and DT are not sorted, but could be if it is important

data types of columns:

- ID - numeric
- DT - date
- BEFORE - character
- AFTER - character

| ID | DT | BEFORE | AFTER |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | 21MAY2021 | PR | P |
| 123 | 28OCT2021 | P | P |
| 123 | 30OCT2023 | P | P |
| 85 | 01AUG2021 | PR | PR |
| 85 | 15AUG2021 | PR | M |
| 85 | 22AUG2021 | M | PR |
| 11 | 25JUN2021 | P | P |
| 122 | 22JUL2021 | PR | PR |
| 444 | 18MAY2022 | PR | M |

And I need to create new binary column "COL1" with values 0/1

- If some client ("ID") changed service from PR (in "BEFORE") to P or M (in "AFTER") and did not return to PR (in "AFTER") service for another 4 or more months ("DT") --> then 1
- If some client changed service from PR (in "BEFORE") to P or M (in "AFTER") and return to PR (in "AFTER") earlier than after 4 months --> then 0
- If client did not make change from PR to P or M --> then 0

So as a result I need something like below:

| ID | DT | BEFORE | AFTER | COL1 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | 21MAY2021 | PR | P | 1 --> changed PR to P and did not back to PR for 4 or more months |
| 123 | 28OCT2021 | P | P | 1 |
| 123 | 30OCT2023 | P | P | 1 |
| 85 | 01AUG2021 | PR | PR | 0 |
| 85 | 15AUG2021 | PR | M | 0 |
| 85 | 22AUG2021 | M | PR | 0 --> back to PR less than 4 months after changing PR to P or M |
| 11 | 25JUN2021 | P | P | 0 --> client did not make change from PR to P or M |
| 122 | 22JUL2021 | PR | PR | 0 --> client did not make change from PR to P or M |
| 444 | 18MAY2022 | PR | M | 1 --> customer changed PR to P or M and we have no further history of changes so 1 |

I totally do not know how to do that in PROC SQL in SAS Enterprise Guide, do you know what to do ?

Comment: How is this different than your previous question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73655547/how-to-create-flag-0-1-inform-whether-was-changed-or-not-during-4-months-between  Why do you want to use SQL?  Why not just do it using normal SAS code?

Comment: Tom - solution presented in my previous question does not work, so I presented my problem more clearly here, of course it do not have to be SQL code, if you are able to solve this problem by SAS code it also could be ok - do you have any idea ? :)

Comment: You probably need to provide more example data.  For example what if someone has an interval of more than 4 months, but then has another that is not more than 4 months?  Should the first one be remembered?  Or does the second failure wipe that out?

Comment: Tom - if at least once in his history of changes he has endured 4 months or more, he has 1 in col1, so the second failure do not "delete" previous "success" from the memory :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably just need to remember the last date that it moved from PR.
You need to process ALL of the records for an ID to figure out the flag value.
You could use a DOW loop for this.

```
data want;
do until (last.id);
  set have;
  by id dt;
  if (before='PR' and after in ('M' 'P')) then from_dt=dt;
  if after='PR' and intnx('month',dt,-4,'s') <= from_dt then from_dt=.;
  if not missing(from_dt) then do;
     if dt > intnx('month',from_dt,4,'s') then flag=1;
  end;
end;
  flag=sum(flag,0);
  format from_dt date9.;
  keep id flag;
run;
```

If you want to merge it back onto the detailed records then use a double DOW loop where the second loop is just to re-read the observations so they can be written out with the FLAG variable set.

```
data want;
do until (last.id);
  set have;
  by id dt;
  if (before='PR' and after in ('M' 'P')) then from_dt=dt;
  if after='PR' and intnx('month',dt,-4,'s') <= from_dt then from_dt=.;
  if not missing(from_dt) then do;
     if dt > intnx('month',from_dt,4,'s') then flag=1;
  end;
end;
  flag=sum(flag,0);
do until (last.id);
  set have;
  by id ;
  output;
end;
  format from_dt date9.;
  drop from_dt;
run;
```

Result

```
Obs     ID           DT    BEFORE    AFTER      from_dt    flag

 1      11    25JUN2021      P        P               .      0
 2      85    01AUG2021      PR       PR              .      0
 3      85    15AUG2021      PR       M               .      0
 4      85    22AUG2021      M        PR              .      0
 5     122    22JUL2021      PR       PR              .      0
 6     123    21MAY2021      PR       P       21MAY2021      1
 7     123    28OCT2021      P        P       21MAY2021      1
 8     123    30OCT2023      P        P       21MAY2021      1
```

Comment: Tom - if at least once in his history of changes he has endured 4 months or more, he has 1 in col1, so the second failure do not "delete" previous "success" from the memory :) Does your code meet this requirement ?

Comment: In that case move the 4 month test inside the DO loop.  Code updated.

Comment: Note that using 4 calendar months is a little problematic as months are not all the same length.  Might be more consistent to use a criteria of 120 days instead.

Comment: Tom - everything is great! But one more think I forgot - when we have only one row per some client where is PR in "BEFORE" and M or P in "AFTER" this kind of client also should have 1 in flag - could you modify your solution for that ?  I presented that in client with ID = 444

Comment: add this statement after the end of the first DO loop. `if first.id and last.id and not missing(from_dt) then flag=1;`

Comment: Tom, could you modify your code with this line? I am not sure about which first DO loop you talk and which place in code do you think, please ?

Comment: Tom, could you modify your code with this line ? I am now sure where should it be "at the end of the first DO loop" ? please

Comment: A DO loop starts with a DO and ends with the matching END.  Notice how I have indented the END to match the indentation of the DO that it ends.  You can figure it out.

Comment: Tom, I understand, but I do not quite know in which indentation I should put this line to be correct, could you modify your code please ? :) SHould this line be between the second "end;" and "flag = sum..." ?

Comment: Tom, should this new line be between lines 10 and 11 ?

Comment: Right.  Note that does not matter logically whether it is before the END of after.  (See if you can convince yourself of why.)  It is just more efficient to have it after since then it only runs once per ID value instead of once per observation.

Comment: Great! Thank you Tom - I gave you best answer, thank you for your help, time and discussion :)